# Stop docker-py events stream iteration

Tags: dockerpy

How can i ask to `docker-py` events to stop `events` stream iterable ? I want, for exemple, simply stop to watch dockers events.

```
from docker import Client


client = Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
events = client.events(decode=True)

for event in events:
    print(event)

print('exited')
```

`client.events()` return generator build [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docker/client.py#L207).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `client.events()` generator is blocking on a unix socket `recv` call.  If you can't wait until the next event and `break` out of the loop then, you'll need to interrupt the socket.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a clean way to do this via docker-py.  The only way I found requires using/overriding private methods which of course is fragile.  If you're looking for a robust solution I would recommend making the api call directly and then you're free to set your own timeouts on the socket or use it in non-blocking mode.

With that being said, to directly answer the question here's a way to patch the `Client` class to add the api response as a property to the generator returned by `events()`.

```py
from docker import Client

class CustomGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, stream, response, decode):
        self.stream = stream
        self.response = response
        self.decode = decode

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in super(CustomClient, self.stream).\
                _stream_helper(self.response, self.decode):
            yield item

class CustomClient(Client):
    def _stream_helper(self, response, decode=False):
        return CustomGenerator(self, response, decode)
```

Once you have the response you can shutdown the socket which will raise an exception in the generator.  In this example I use a thread to stop listening after 5 seconds.

```py
from threading import Timer
import requests
import socket

client = CustomClient(base_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock")
events = client.events()

def listen_for_events():
    print("listening")

    try:
        for event in events:
            print(event)
    except requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError:
        pass

    print("done listening")

def stop_listening():
    sock = client._get_raw_response_socket(events.response)
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)

Timer(5, stop_listening).start()

listen_for_events()
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to interrupt wait for the next event you can employ `since` and `until` arguments of `events()` method by listening events in series of two second timeframes.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import docker
client = docker.from_env()

delta = timedelta(seconds=2)
since = datetime.utcnow()
until = datetime.utcnow() + delta
while True:
    for event in client.events(since=since, until=until, decode=True):
        print(event)
    since = until
    until = datetime.utcnow() + delta
```

Since you wait for events for 2 seconds, you execution thread will be blocked for maximum 2 seconds. So, if user hits `Ctrl+C`, the script will terminate shortly.